# problema con inicializar array de objeto por culpa de la propiedad de la variable

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular5

Tengo la siguiente clase o modelo:

```
export class Cuota{
    constructor(
        public _id: string,
        public name: string, 
        public description: string,
        public precio: number
    ){}
}
```

a la hora de inicializar este clase en mi componente me sale error en el array porque es un array de strings y tengo puesto el precio como tipo number.

```
export class CuotaComponent implements OnInit{

public cuota: Cuota;


  constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private _router: Router, 
    private _userService: UserService,
    private _cuotaService: CuotaService,
  ){
    this.cuota = new Cuota('','','','');
  }
```

Tengo varias dudas que aprovecho para mencionar va relacionado con el tema.

En rendimiento en un proyecto MEAN es útil poner la propiedad que le toca a cada variable del objeto, es que entro en la base de datos de node y lo veo todo en formato JSON y uno piensa si realmente es necesario declarar propiedades tipo number o date.

Otra duda que tengo es entre declarar el objeto en una interface o en una classe.

que hay de diferente? debería crear una interface en vez de una classe?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

hay varias cosas para ver aquí.
Primero es el constructor de la clase `Cuota`. Si el tercer parámetro es un numero no entiendo por que le pasas un string.

Tu construcutor debería ser asi:

```
this.cuota = new Cuota('','','', 0);
```

Aquí no estás usando ningún array, solo parámetros sueltos. En este caso puedes poner el tipo de dato que necesites sin problema.

Ahora si tu modelo debería ser una interfaz o una clase depende de la funcionalidad que vaya a tener el model. Esto es algo básico en programación orientada a objetos, si todavía no conoces la diferencia entre interfaz o clase, deberías repasar estos conceptos antes de continuar con tu aplicación.

[Aquí](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) puedes ver que es una interfaz y como implementarlas en Typescript (la documentación está en inglés).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. El problema es que no quiero hardcodear nada a ese array quiero que esté vacío el número. No he programado mucho en este tipo de lenguajes y me estoy metiendo ahora. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda